# Composite function and binomial.

Tags: polynomials

$
f(x) = x + x^2 + x^4 + x^8 + x^{16} + x^{32} + \dots$

Then coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $f(f(x))$ is?

Solution:
We can write $f(f(x)) = f(x) + f(x)^2 + f(x)^4 + \dots$

Then, coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $f(x)= 0$ and the 
            coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $(f(x))^2 = 2$
as $(2,8)$ and $(8,2)$ are the two exponent combinations but how to find coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $f(x)^4$ and so on?

Comment: Why is the first summand $x$ in your sum?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I assume because $x^{2^0}=x^1=x$.

Comment: @M.Winter Yes that's correct

Comment: The sum of exponent should be ten 8+2=10

Comment: You can start by noticing that the tail end $x^{12}+x^{14}+x^{16}+\dots$ contributes nothing to the coefficient of $x^{10}$ because the powers are too large. This means the coefficient of of $x^{10}$ in $f(f(x))$ is the same as the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the polynomial $g(g(x))$, where $g(x)=x+x^2+x^4+\dots+x^{10}$. Now you can work it out explicitly using the binomial theorem.

Comment: @JoeWebster But the series is different

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, 
$$ f(f(x)) = f(x)+f(x)^2+f(x)^4+f(x)^8+f(x)^{16}+\ldots $$
on the other hand $f(x)^m = x^m +o(x^{m})$, hence
$$ [x^{10}]f(f(x)) = [x^{10}]\left( f(x)+ f(x)^2+f(x)^4 + f(x)^8 \right) $$
and 
$$[x^{10}]f(x)^m = \left|\left\{(a_1,\ldots,a_m): a_1+\ldots+a_m=10, a_k = 2^j\right\}\right|. $$
In particular $[x^{10}]f(x)=0$ (trivial by inspection), $[x^{10}]f(x)^2 = 2 $ since $10=2+8=8+2$, 
$[x^{10}]f(x)^4 = 10$ since $10=4+4+1+1=4+2+2+2$ and $[x^{10}]f(x)^8=28$ since $10=1+1+1+1+1+1+2+2$. The final outcome is 
$$ [x^{10}]f(f(x)) = 0+2+10+28 = \color{red}{40}.$$